# How to get the product of two matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

I Have this code:

```
import numpy as np 

a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([4,5,6])
```

And I would like to get from `a` and `b` this matrix:

```
c = np.array([4,10,18])
```

I mean

```
c = np.array([a0*b0, a1*b1, a2*b2])
```

without a `for` loop. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

numpy arrays support vectorized operators, so `a * b` will return your required array.

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([4, 5, 6])
print(a*b)
# [ 4 10 18]
```